# X label in multiple bars and problem in bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Can someone help me in this problem? I am trying to draw an histogram, but I am having some problems. This is the histogram I have made so far:

```
    \begin{center}
 \pgfplotstableread{
1 800   900     780
2 750   0       683 
3 678   800     609  
4 600   0       683   
}\dataset
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
        width=\textwidth,
        title={\textit{Analysis}},
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width=0.2,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1000,        
        ylabel={Population},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        xticklabels = {
            Men,
            Women,
            Men,
            Women,
        },
        major x tick style = {opacity=0},
        minor x tick num = 0,
        minor tick length=3ex,
        ]
\addplot

[draw=black,fill=black!10] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset; %Data1
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset; %Data2
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!70] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset; %Data3
\legend{1,2,3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

My problems are:

- Some bars have a 0 value and I want to eliminate it: how can I do? Or better, how can I accost the two other bars eliminating totally the 0 bar?
- I want to add other 2 labels below the labels "Men" and "Women": the first label should refer to the first two groups of bars "Men - Women", and the second to the second group. But I have no idea how can I do it.
- Finally, how can I add bar errors?

Thank you so much for your help.